# Left-align Two-column Glossary for English Words

Tags: glossaries, xindy, xepersian

I have used `glossaries` package in order to produce an English-Persian and Persian-English dictionary, with a style which I found [here](http://parsilatex.com/site/1401/08/create-a-glossary-in-xepersian/). But regrettably, the English words are not left-aligned as you can observe in the below image, and I really do need the glossaries to be two-columned. Is there a way so that the English phrases to be left-aligned?
[image]

Here is what I consider a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[square,comma,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hyperindex=true,pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym,nonumberlist=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage[perpagefootnote=on]{bidi}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
%%%%%% ============================================================================================================

\newglossarystyle{myFaToEn}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentryname{##1}\dotfill\space \glsentrytext{##1}
        
    }
}


\newglossarystyle{myEntoFa}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{LTR}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentrytext{##1}\dotfill\space \glsentryname{##1}
        
    }
}

\newglossarystyle{myAbbrlist}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{LTR}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentrytext{##1}\dotfill\space \Glsentrylong{##1}
        
    }
    \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{\rl{فهرست اختصارات}}
}
\newglossary[glg]{english}{gls}{glo}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
\newglossary[blg]{persian}{bls}{blo}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}
\makeglossaries
\glsdisablehyper
\let\oldgls\gls
\let\oldglspl\glspl
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\gls}{\@ifstar\@msgls\@mgls}
\newcommand*{\@mgls}[1] {\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\oldgls{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\lr{\oldgls{#1}}}}
\newcommand*{\@msgls}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\glstext{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\lr{\glsentryname{#1}}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\glspl}{\@ifstar\@msglspl\@mglspl}
\newcommand*{\@mglspl}[1] {\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\oldglspl{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldglspl{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\@msglspl}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\glsplural{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\glsentryplural{#1}}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\newword}[4]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}     {type={english},name={\lr{#2}},plural={#4},text={#3},description={}}
    \newglossaryentry{f-#1} {type={persian},name={#3},text={\lr{#2}},description={}}
}
%%%%%% ============================================================================================================
%%============================ 
\newcommand{\printabbreviation}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \baselineskip=.75cm

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{فهرست اختصارات}
    \setglossarystyle{myAbbrlist}
    \begin{LTR}
        \Oldprintglossary[type=acronym] 
    \end{LTR}
    \clearpage
}%

\newcommand{\printacronyms}{\printabbreviation}
\let\Oldprintglossary\printglossary
\renewcommand{\printglossary}{
    \let\appendix\relax
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \twocolumn{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
    \setglossarystyle{myEntoFa}
    \LTRdblcol
    \Oldprintglossary[type=english]

    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}
    \setglossarystyle{myFaToEn}
    \RTLdblcol
    
    \Oldprintglossary[type=persian]
    \onecolumn{}
}%
%%%%%%
\input{testgloss}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{فصل ۱}
    از فرایندهای BALAS و GOMORY در بخش ۲-۲-۴ نام برده شده اما طرح آن‌ها در فصل ۱ انجام گرفته. احتمالاً باید در بخش  طرح شود.
    هایپرلینک مسائل ۴-۸۶ و ۴-۸۷ در بخش اول توضیحات فصل دوم اضافه شود.
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, there are three `xindy` commands which need to be executed before any glossary is printed:

```
xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.glg -o %.gls %.glo
xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.blg -o %.bls %.blo
xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M %.xdy -t %.alg -o %.acr %.acn
```

Edit: Here is the content of `testgloss.tex` file which I have forgotten to include:

```
\newword{Knapsackproblem}{Knapsack problem}{مسئلهٔ کوله‌پشتی}{}
\newword{ZerooneLP}{Zero-one integer programming}{برنامه‌ریزی عدد صحیحِ صفر-یک}{}
\newword{w1}{Covering problem}{مسئلهٔ پوشش}{}
\newword{w2}{Packing problem}{مسئلهٔ بسته‌بندی}{}
\newword{w3}{Polynomial time}{زمان چندجمله‌ای}{}
\newword{w4}{Special-purpose method}{روش تک‌منظوره}{}
\newword{w5}{Size}{اندازه}{}
\newword{w6}{Approximation algorithm}{الگوریتم تقریبی}{}
\newword{w7}{Cutting stock problem}{مسئلهٔ برش چوب}{}
\newword{w8}{Loading problem}{مسئلهٔ بارگیری}{}
\newword{w9}{Bin-packing problem}{مسئلهٔ بسته‌بندی با جعبه}{}
\newword{w10}{Scheduling problem}{مسئلهٔ زمان‌بندی}{}
\newword{w11}{Feasible}{شدنی}{}
\newword{w12}{Assignment}{تخصیص}{}
\newword{w13}{Weight}{وزن}{}
\newword{w14}{Bounded Knapsack Problem (BKP)}{مسئلهٔ کوله‌پشتی کران‌دار}{}
\newword{w15}{General Knapsack Problem (GKP)}{مسئلهٔ کوله‌پشتی کلی}{}
\newword{w16}{Unbounded Knapsack Problem}{مسئلهٔ کوله‌پشتی بی‌کران}{}
\newword{w17}{Unbounded change-making problem}{مسئلهٔ پول-خردْکردن بی‌کران}{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MWE is missing the other file that you have used to define your glossary words (`testgloss.tex`). Nevertheless, I reproduced your issue and here is how you can fix it.

First, I reordered things so that the first line always includes the English text, as this is the En2Fa dictionary, so the first element that gets read is the English term. Then the Persian text comes and if it cannot fit in the same line, then the remaining part is aligned to the right side.

```
\newglossarystyle{myEntoFa}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{latin} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{latin}}
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\begin{latin}\noindent\glsentryname{##1}\dotfill\space \noindent\raggedleft{\rl{\glsentrytext{##1}}} \end{latin}}
}
```

[image]

And if you really want to have the English text to break into multiple lines instead of the Persian text, then you can do something like this:

```
\newglossarystyle{myEntoFa}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{latin} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{latin}}
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\raggedright{\rl{\glsentrytext{##1}}}\dotfill\space \noindent\lr{\glsentryname{##1}} \\}
}
```

[image]